# How to make a systemd service restart some other service?

Tags: systemd, services

I have an *application* that reads from a database on startup which is updated daily by a *separate updater*, described by the following `systemd` units:

`application.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Application reading database
Wants=network-online.target
After=local-fs.target network-online.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
User=application
Group=application
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/application
ExecStart=/var/lib/application/application-exec --database /var/db/database.db
StandardOutput=file:/var/lib/application/application.stdout.log
StandardError=file:/var/lib/application/application.stderr.log

StartLimitInterval=60
StartLimitBurst=10
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`updater.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Database updater
Wants=network-online.target
After=local-fs.target network-online.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=updater
Group=updater
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/updater
ExecStart=/var/lib/updater/updater-exec --database /var/db/database.db
StandardOutput=file:/var/lib/updater/updater.stdout.log
StandardError=file:/var/lib/updater/updater.stderr.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`updater.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for database updater

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=900
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**My question:**

How can I make the *updater service* restart the *application service* if the update was performed successfully (so that the application re-reads the now updated database; success/failure is indicated by the updater's exit code)?

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/963511/systemd-how-do-i-automatically-reload-a-unit-when-another-oneshot-service-is) on *serverfault* is similar, but sadly does not have an answer that is applicable to my use case.

Comment: Maybe add this to the end of your exec line in the updater.service file?    `&& systemctl restart application.service`   I am putting this as a comment because I have not tested this. The command should only run if the updater exec call returns success.

Comment: @JG7 This won't work as the updater's `ExecStart=` is executed in the context of `User=updater`. User `updater` does not have sufficient permissions to restart services

Comment: I see now. Thanks for the clarity. I hope larsks solution works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution turned out to be much simpler than expected. The following line needs to be added to `updater.service`:

```
ExecStartPost=+/usr/bin/systemctl restart application.service
```

Resulting `updater.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Database updater
Wants=network-online.target
After=local-fs.target network-online.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=updater
Group=updater
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/updater
ExecStart=/var/lib/updater/updater-exec --database /var/db/database.db
StandardOutput=file:/var/lib/updater/updater.stdout.log
StandardError=file:/var/lib/updater/updater.stderr.log
ExecStartPost=+/usr/bin/systemctl restart application.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Relevant excerpts from `man 5 systemd.service`:

```
├───────┼────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"+"    │ If the executable path is prefixed     │
│       │ with "+" then the process is executed  │
│       │ with full privileges. In this mode     │
│       │ privilege restrictions configured with │
│       │ User=, Group=, CapabilityBoundingSet=  │
│       │ or the various file system namespacing │
│       │ options (such as PrivateDevices=,      │
│       │ PrivateTmp=) are not applied to the    │
│       │ invoked command line (but still affect │
│       │ any other ExecStart=, ExecStop=, ...   │
│       │ lines).                                │
├───────┼────────────────────────────────────────┤
```

```
ExecStartPost= commands are only run after the commands specified in ExecStart= have been invoked
successfully, as determined by Type= (i.e. the process has been started for Type=simple or Type=idle,
the last ExecStart= process exited successfully for Type=oneshot, the initial process exited
successfully for Type=forking, "READY=1" is sent for Type=notify, or the BusName= has been taken for
Type=dbus).
```

**Explanation:**

- `ExecStartPost=` command is executed with root privileges due to preceding `+` (see first excerpt), which allows restarting `application.service` using `systemctl` despite specifying `User=` and `Group=`
- `ExecStartPost=` command is only executed if `ExecStart=` command succeeds (see second excerpt), which allows a conditional restart of `application.service`

Answer (score 3):

This was a fun one to figure out!

We're going to add a third service to the mix, `restart-application.service`, and then arrange dependencies between `restart-applicationservice` and `updater.service` such that:

- Starting `restart-application.service` starts `updater.service`
- `restart-application.service` doesn't actually run until `updater.service` has finished.
- `restart-application.service` doesn't run unless `updater.service` is successful.

We create `restart-application.service` like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart application
BindsTo=updater.service
After=updater.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart application
```

We're using a [`BindsTo`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#BindsTo=) dependency here. The key part of the documentation is:

> When used in conjunction with After= on the same unit the behaviour of BindsTo= is even stronger. In this case, the unit bound to strictly has to be in active state for this unit to also be in active state.

Now we modify the `Unit` section of `updater.service` to look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Database updater
Wants=network-online.target
After=local-fs.target network-online.target nss-lookup.target
StopWhenUnneeded=true
```

And the `Service` section to include:

```
RemainAfterExit=true
```

These changes mean that (a) `updater.service` will remain "active" after the `ExecStart` command completes; we need this because `restart-application.service` will only run if this one is active. The `StopWhenUnneeded=true` option means that the unit will become inactive when nothing else depends on it (i.e., when `restart-application.service` has stopped).

Finally, we need to modify your timer to start `restart-application.service` instead of `updater.service`.

---

I've created a dummy `application.service` (that just runs a simple webserver) and a dummy `updater.service` that will randomly succeed or fail:

```
[Unit]
Description=Database updater
Wants=network-online.target
After=local-fs.target network-online.target nss-lookup.target
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=updater
Group=updater
WorkingDirectory=/home/updater
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'rc=$(( RANDOM % 2 )); echo "rc=$rc"; exit $rc'
RemainAfterExit=true
```

Let's watch the logs when we `systemctl start restart-application.service`. Here's what happens when `updater.service` fails;

```
... systemd[1]: Starting updater.service - Database updater...
... bash[1253]: rc=1
... systemd[1]: updater.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
... systemd[1]: updater.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
... systemd[1]: Failed to start updater.service - Database updater.
... systemd[1]: Dependency failed for restart-application.service - Restart application.
... systemd[1]: restart-application.service: Job restart-application.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

And here's what happens when `updater.service` is successful:

```
... systemd[1]: Starting updater.service - Database updater...
... systemd[1]: Finished updater.service - Database updater.
... darkhttpd[1193]: darkhttpd/1.13, copyright (c) 2003-2021 Emil Mikulic.
... darkhttpd[1193]: listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080/
... systemd[1]: Starting restart-application.service - Restart application...
... bash[1262]: rc=0
... systemd[1]: Stopping application.service - Application reading database...
... systemd[1]: application.service: Deactivated successfully.
... systemd[1]: Stopped application.service - Application reading database.
... systemd[1]: Started application.service - Application reading database.
... systemd[1]: restart-application.service: Deactivated successfully.
... systemd[1]: Finished restart-application.service - Restart application.
... systemd[1]: updater.service: Deactivated successfully.
... systemd[1]: Stopped updater.service - Database updater.
```

Status of everything at this point:

```
# systemctl status application.service updater.service restart-application.service
● application.service - Application reading database
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/application.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-09-17 20:48:27 UTC; 1min 53s ago
   Main PID: 1264 (darkhttpd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4661)
     Memory: 172.0K
        CPU: 1ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/application.service
             └─ 1264 /usr/sbin/darkhttpd /home/application/htdocs --port 8080

○ updater.service - Database updater
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/updater.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

○ restart-application.service - Restart application
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/restart-application.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

I think that does everything you want.

Comment: This looks *very* promising. I'll test this and give feedback. Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: This approach works, but I figured out a simpler solution which requires only minor alterations and is overall more logical (in my opinion).